# ! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I have an issue when compiling the following code snippet :

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Synth\`se des FoM dans le cas (GC$_{\text{phot}}$ + WL) versus XC dans les cas (Y1,Y10) et (Flat,Non-Flat).}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xcccc}
\hline
\rowcolor{jonquil} \multicolumn{1} {l}{\textbf{Synth\`ese des contraintes avec la somme des 2 sondes GC$_{\text{phot}}$ et WL compar\'ee \`a la cross-correlation XC}}  \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{FoM} & \rowcolor{lavender(web)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{WL FLAT-Y1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{WL NON-FLAT-Y1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GC$_{\text{phot}}$ FLAT-Y1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GC$_{\text{phot}}$ NON-FLAT-Y10} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{FoM} & \rowcolor{lavender} 0.5676 & 0.1678 & 56.88 & 33.60  \\
\hline
& \rowcolor{lavender(web)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{WL FLAT-Y10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{WL NON-FLAT-Y10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GC$_{\text{phot}}$ FLAT-Y10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GC$_{\text{phot}}$ NON-FLAT-Y10} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{FoM} &  7.35 & 2.13 & 649.59 & 353.40 \\
& \rowcolor{lavender(web)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{WL + GC$_{\text{phot}}$ FLAT-Y1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{WL + GC$_{\text{phot}}$ NON-FLAT-Y1} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{WL + GC$_{\text{phot} FLAT-Y10} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{WL + GC$_{\text{phot}}$ NON-FLAT-Y10} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{FoM} & 7.35 & 2.13 & 649.59 & 353.40 \\
& \rowcolor{lavender(web)} \multicolumn{1}{c}{XC FLAT-Y1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{XC NON-FLAT-Y1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{XC FLAT-Y10} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{XC NON-FLAT-Y10} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{FoM}  \multicolumn{1}{c}{FoM}  & 122.24 & 61.88 & 1599.25 & 741.38 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{synthesis_LSST}
\end{table}
```

The error is with `pdflatex`:

```
Runaway argument?
{Xcccc} \hline \rowcolor {jonquil} \multicolumn {1} {l}{\textbf {Synt\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

If I ignore this error, I can get th final result on image below :

[image: final result]

This is almost the expected result except :

1) As you can see, the width of the table is too large, I would like to reduce the space between fields, how is it possible ?

2) I would like to put the term `FoM`on the left of the table : maybe the fact that currently it's centered, causes the width of table of be too large in my report page.

Any help is welcome, Regards

Comment: Please, make a compilable example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Apart from that, there is at least one `$` missing and as you were already told in the comments to your previous question, `\rowcolor` has to be the first thing in a row.

Comment: Could you please complete your example code by adding the documentclas as well as the relevant packages? If you use the `geometry` package, could you please also add these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In comparison to the original, I have added the missing `}$` in line 25, removed all the superfluous `\multicolumn{1}{c}` commands, replaced the `\rowcolor` commands by the more automated `\rowcolors{2}{white}{lavender}` command. I have also replaced the accents by accents that I directly entered through the keyboard. Lastly, I have also changes the column specifiers to allos for linebreaks in the last four cells. Otherwise your table would be too wide for the textwidth. (For my MWE I had to guess some settings, as there was no preamble given in the question.)

If you want to decrease the space between the columns, you can use `\setlength{\tabcolspe}{} (default width is 6pt).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table,svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{jonquil}{RGB}{255,224,85}
\definecolor{lavender}{RGB}{229,229,251}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Synthèse des FoM dans le cas (GC$_{\text{phot}}$ + WL) versus XC dans les cas (Y1,Y10) et (Flat,Non-Flat).}
\footnotesize
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{white}{lavender}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lCCCC}
\hline
\rowcolor{jonquil}\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\textbf{Synthèse des contraintes avec la somme des 2 sondes GC$_{\text{phot}}$ et WL compareé à la cross-correlation XC}}  \\
 &  WL FLAT-Y1 & WL NON-FLAT-Y1 & GC$_{\text{phot}}$ FLAT-Y1 & GC$_{\text{phot}}$ NON-FLAT-Y10 \\
\hline
 FoM &  0.5676 & 0.1678 & 56.88 & 33.60  \\
\hline
&  WL FLAT-Y10 & WL NON-FLAT-Y10 & GC$_{\text{phot}}$ FLAT-Y10 & GC$_{\text{phot}}$ NON-FLAT-Y10 \\
FoM &  7.35 & 2.13 & 649.59 & 353.40 \\
 &  WL + GC$_{\text{phot}}$ FLAT-Y1 & WL + GC$_{\text{phot}}$ NON-FLAT-Y1 &  WL + GC$_{\text{phot}}$ FLAT-Y10 &  WL + GC$_{\text{phot}}$ NON-FLAT-Y10 \\
FoM & 7.35 & 2.13 & 649.59 & 353.40 \\
 & XC FLAT-Y1 & XC NON-FLAT-Y1 & XC FLAT-Y10 & XC NON-FLAT-Y10 \\
FoM  & 122.24 & 61.88 & 1599.25 & 741.38 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{synthesis_LSST}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! it works perfectly !